# Missing radio buttons in closing question popup

Tags: bug

[image]

I wanted to recommend closing one of the questions, but the popup to select my motivation  lacks radio buttons.

Occurs only for this [question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5216/how-to-checkin-eclipse-code-into-git-repository-in-projectlocker) but not for others, e.g., [this one](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/qc-report-which-test-cases-have-not-been-linked-to-at-least-one-test-set).

Comment: Was it previously closed then re-opened? For whatever reason, it says you've already voted to close it.

Comment: Mea culpa, my eyes are deceiving me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect has happened is that you had a close vote on it, but it expired. Close votes are not supposed to expire on questions with less than 100 views, but it appears it did anyway.

I believe if you have a vote on it, but the vote expires or is otherwise nullified, you're still prevented from closing it again because you only ever get one vote per question. Voting is supposed to be a "spontaneous event by the community" apparently.

It may also have expired because of my "leave open" review on it. I had given the OP an opportunity to reign the question on topic. Either it was truly non-salvageable or he was simply unwilling to do so, so I closed it. I was not aware a leave open review would remove close votes; I'll keep an eye out for that in the future.